# Passing data from Controller to View without changing the Route

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Say I have several Controllers, including a `BaseControlelr` and I want to do some queries and send the data to my `Index.cshtml`, but I'm not changing the url since this is a single page application. Normally I'd define a Route for my `Get` request and retrieve it using Angular `$http.get`, but is there any other way I can pass the model directly from my controller to my view?

Comment: you can have a method inside your controller which will make an Ajax using `$http` and you will use that data returned by ajax.

Comment: I'm looking for a not-ajax method

Comment: I can understand the question, but what problem are using $scope or vm.this?

Comment: Nothing actually! I'm just curious I guess

Comment: How about invoking a child action using Html.Action("method", "controller") inside Index.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is there any other way I can pass the model directly from my
>   controller to my view?

Of course that there is. In ASP.NET MVC a controller action can return a view model to a strongly typed view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view you could just serialize this view model as an [`Angular constant`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) available to your Angular application:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script>
    angular.module('myApp').constant('model', @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
</script>
```

Now in your Angular application you can play with this `model` variable:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'model', function($scope, model) {
    $scope.model = model;
}]);
```

And in the corresponding template:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Hello {{FirstName}} {{LastName}}
</div>
```

That's of course the initial bootstrapping of your SPA. From there on you might need to use pure client side techniques to work with the model.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there is more than one model needed to pass into `Index.cshtml`?

Comment: Wow, how would this even make sense? Let's repeat the very basics of the pattern you are using: MVC: `M` stands for Model, `V` stands for View and `C` stands for Controller. So talking about having different models in a single view contradicts to the entire paradigm of the very framework you are using.

Comment: That makes sense in the situation, but I guess your answer is "no, you can't do this"

Comment: If you need different *models* (see I made *models* in italics) in a single view, then you will write a view model that has as properties all those *models*. And it is this view model that will act as the `M` in the design pattern you are using.